# ngOnChanges not always firing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

As the title suggests I am having a problem with `ngOnChanges` activating correctly but the two listings below do something I find quite odd. The first listing never gets into the `ngOnChanges` method and the second one always does. It is essentially the same method with a different body for the first `if` statement.

never hits:

```
async ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): Promise<void> 
{
  if(changes.selectedImage)//{console.log("Changing ...")}
  {
    this.tileSource = await this.fetchCurrentTileSource();
    if(this.tileSource)
    {
       this.refreshImageLayer(this.tileSource);
    }    
  }
}
```

always hits

```
async ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): Promise<void> 
{
  if(changes.selectedImage){console.log("Changing ...")}
  /* {
    this.tileSource = await this.fetchCurrentTileSource();
    if(this.tileSource)
    {
      this.refreshImageLayer(this.tileSource);
    }    
  } */
}
```

Component (contains method above):

```
@Component({
  selector: 'camera-check-viewer',
  template: ''
})

export class CameraCheckViewerComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {

...

@Input() public selectedImage: CaptureQueryResponseItem;
```

Containing Component:

```
export class CameraCheckPhotoViewerComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnChanges, OnDestroy {

...

@ViewChild(CameraCheckViewerComponent, {static: true}) cameraCheckViewer: CameraCheckViewerComponent

...

public selectedCapture: CaptureQueryResponseItem;

...

 ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
   if (changes['selectedBoothCameraId']) {
       this.hideCameraFailedNotesModal();
       this.loadImages();
   }
 }
```

Within loadImages:

```
this.selectedCapture = Object.assign({}, capture); //Force change detection, not sure required!
```

and the html:

```
<div class="check-camera-wrapper">
  <camera-check-viewer class="check-camera-view"
     [selectedImage]="selectedCapture"
     (click)="$event.stopPropagation()">
  </camera-check-viewer>
</div>
```

Place a breakpoint on the first `if` statement with the `console.log` body and it executes, change the commenting so the other body is active and it never executes. I don't understand why this happens so does anyone have any idea as to what is happening here?

Comment: Put a console before and after this.tileSource and see what fires. Maybe your promise simply never resolves?

Comment: @MikeOne thanks that shows me that it is executed it just won't break on the if statement when I have the body I want. I added console statements and a breakpointon this.tilesource and it broke correctly. I then removed the console statements and it still broke correctly. Do you know why?